# Convert XML CDATA format into JSON format in dataweave 2.0 Mule4

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

Below is my sample XML response

```
<DATA><![CDATA[
<RESULT>0</RESULT>
<Addresses>
<Address>
 ...............
</Address>
<Address>
 ...............
</Address>
<Address>
 ...............
</Address>
</Addresses>

]]></DATA>
```

I want to transform this into a JSON array of objects. I used the below code, but it is just returning the CDATA string, not in JSON format

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json encoding="UTF-8"
---
payload
```

I'm using dataweave 2.0 in Mule 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complementing Salim's answer, you can try the following DataWeave expression in order to get access to the Addresses element:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
read("<root>" ++ payload.DATA ++ "</root>", "application/xml").root.Addresses
```

The idea is to wrap the DATA content with a root node, and then use it to access the inner elements.

Answer (score 3):

Try with this script:

**Input**

```
<DATA><![CDATA[
<Person>
<RESULT>0</RESULT>
<Addresses>
<Address>
 ...............
</Address>
<Address>
 ...............
</Address>
<Address>
 ...............
</Address>
</Addresses>
</Person>

]]></DATA>
```

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
read(payload.DATA, "application/xml")
```

**Output**

```
{
  "Person": {
    "RESULT": "0",
    "Addresses": {
      "Address": "\n ...............\n",
      "Address": "\n ...............\n",
      "Address": "\n ...............\n"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code. I tried your solution, I'm getting <RESULT>0</RESULT>
...' as 'application/XML' cause by:
Illegal to have multiple roots (start tag in epilog?). error

Comment: Your xml is malformed. Need to have one root element and the rest can be nested under that root node. XML does not allow multiple root elements.

Comment: I updated your input sample in my answer. HTH

Comment: This is the XML response which I get. Can we add or remove the root element using dataweave code??

Comment: Adresses is a array,address is object I need the result as array of objects.

Comment: that you can not make here for that you need to make XML to JSON and then break JSON in two parts 1. REMOVE addresses and then make it an array and add back to old JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I followed your directions and it worked.
Transformer 1:

### %dw 2.0
output application/json

read(payload.DATA, "application/xml")

Transformer 2:

### %dw 2.0
output application/java

write(payload,'application/xml')

thanks
dk